# Setting a gridview column to contain links, where the bound data is a list of URLs

Tags: asp.net

I have an object that I retrieve from a database, where one of the fields is a URL.  I am displaying this data in a gridview, and I'd like the URL column to be a series of links saying "Download", where it points to the corresponding URL.

I currently have the following:

```
<asp:GridView ID="my_gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "false" 
            GridLines="None" Width="100%" AllowSorting="True" 
            CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#F5F5F5" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields = "location" Text = "Download link" HeaderText = "Download"  />
            </Columns>    
        </asp:GridView>
```

This doesn't appear to be working.  The entries are blue like a link, but hovering over with a mouse doesn't actually invoke a URL (the cursor does not change to the "link" cursor).  Looking at the generated HTML, they are `<a>` tags but they contain no `href` attrivute.  Why?  What have I missed to allow this to work?  I populate with the following:

```
        private void populateElementView()
        {
            List<MyElement> elements = database.getGeneratedElements();
            // elements has a .location property
            my_gv.DataSource = elements;
            my_gv.DataBind();

        }
```

For further information, the URLs point to files on a computer.  Hand-inserting an item with the url "testing" actually works, while the actual file paths do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this may be it will help you. Here I am using [DataNavigateUrlFormatString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datanavigateurlformatstring.aspx) which is used for

`Gets or sets the string that specifies the format in which the URLs for the hyperlinks in a HyperLinkField object are rendered.`

```
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields = "location" Text = "Download link" HeaderText = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}" />
```

Edit :

You can put your files on server location and your location field will have virtual path like this `MusicFiles/File1.avi`

Now you can format your url in `HyperLinkField` as  `http://localhost//Download/{0}` where {0} means MusicFiles/File1.avi or you `location` field value

```
<asp:HyperLinkField  DataNavigateUrlFields = "location" Text = "Download link" HeaderText = "Download" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http://localhost//Download/{0}" />
```

I think this will help you when you deploy it and user can download the files from your server.

Comment: Didn't change anything, thank you though.  It appears to have something to do with how asp parses URLs.  Would spaces be an issue?

Comment: Have your url contains http or something like this protocols. and yes space may be an issue? can you show what exact value, your location field has.

Comment: Here is a sample: C:/Program Files (x86)/foo/bar/test_file.avi

Comment: I have seen it that when I use http with this, the url link works but with local file location it is not working. So why don't you try with localhost.it will work with it. should i updated the answer for localhost or you got it..?

Comment: Prefixing it with localhost gives the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)" at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" Text="Download link" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("location")%>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

or if you using another control just bind value to NavigateUrl this way:

```
<%# Eval("location")%>
```