# Click Gridview row download particular file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my application, I have a gridview control with 6 columns. When I click on the 6th column row I need to download that file. I am binding gridview from database. How can I take gridview column as like a link?

My markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" Width="950px" CssClass="Grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-ForeColor="White" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SName" HeaderText="SName" />                        
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Size" HeaderText="Size(MB)" />     
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Time" HeaderText="Time" />                             
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="FileName" DataNavigateUrlFields="Id" HeaderText="File Name" ItemStyle-Width = "150" />
    </Columns>        
</asp:GridView>
```

My image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfDln.png)

Comment: What file you want to download? is its Url is available in the binding collecion?

Comment: my gridview binding from database but how can i take gridview column is it ok to take hyperlink filed can you tell me another way to take gridview column as a link filed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a gridview column to contain links, where the bound data is a list of URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362545/setting-a-gridview-column-to-contain-links-where-the-bound-data-is-a-list-of-ur)

Answer (score 0):

Go through this C# code for downloading the file with the specified name in the specified path. I hope this will help.

```
    String pathOfFile = Server.MapPath("~/ActualPathOfYourFile/" +  fileNameComingFromDatabse);
    byte[] bts = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathOfFile);
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bts.Length.ToString());
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileNameComingFromDatabse);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bts);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

Comment: when i click grid view file name column row how can i hold that contains particular row text into a  string

Comment: Hi @Amit-ghute. i am taking this gridview selected row text  `string filename = e.CommandArgument.ToString(); GridViewRow selectedRow = GridView1.Rows[filename];  
            string AccGroupName = GridView1.DataKeys[filename].Values["Account Group"].ToString();   
            string GroupShortName = GridView1.DataKeys[filename].Values["Short Name"].ToString();` i am getting error how can i take this